# Using vintella for SSO, getting vsj authentication was not performed for this request

Tags: single-sign-on, spnego

When vintella tries to get credentials to use the currently logged in user in Windows, I get vsj authentication was not performed for this request in the stack trace. Using google has proven worthless as it seems nobody has gotten this error seemingly ever.  When tomcat starts, it does get a ticket from the SPN, it's only when the application tries to authenticate after SPNEGO.  Anybody else seen this?  I'm thinking I may have to go directly to the SSO vendor, I just dont have any level of support with them.

Comment: Share the stacktrace! What is your Tomcat version?